# How can I make dd not copy empty space when copying a partition to an image file?

Tags: macos, partition

In my scenario, I wanted to use **dd** to copy the contents of a Windows 10 USB installer onto an image file to test if it works. The original windows 10 image was only about 5GB. The newly created image however had the size of ~16GB, which is the size of my USB capacity.

With dd, I am planning to put a ready windows partition onto an image file so it is disposable on different hard disks, and I do not want the empty space to be copied with it, as the partition sizes will be different. Is there any option that prevents dd from copying empty space of a volume onto the image file?

---

I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11.3

---

As mentioned by Mark in the comments, Windows checks the hardware on start to make a partition copy impossible. My question is then changed to asking about the feasibility of the above on a generic OS that does not have this check.

Comment: Which `dd` options did you use? Why do you want to use `dd` (instead of e.g. Disk Utility)?

Comment: @patrix I always use `sudo dd if=/dev/diskXsX of=~/Desktop/image.dmg bs=1m`. I also don't have experience with using disk utility to achieve the task mentioned above, especially not with the El-Capitan update.

Comment: `dd` is block a copier and (partition table|file system|file) agnostic. So simply truncating blocks only containing zeros will either corrupt the output file of the disk, the volume or the file.

Comment: @klanomath How can I then achieve the goal of copying a bootcamp windows volume to an image file, and deploy it elsewhere? Is it possible?

Comment: @TheBro21 You mean an image of a ready-installed and a fully bootable Windows partition for different Macs or even PCs?

Comment: @klanomath Yes, that is what I intend to do

Comment: Doesn't Windows check hardware on boot up if so copying a machine like this won't work without doing something else?

Comment: @Mark I am not aware of that. If it truly is impossible thanks to this, then my questions shall be changed from Windows to a generic OS